# Contained Languages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, embed

I found something called [Contained Languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166334%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). I would like to embed my DSL into C#, without implementing whole language service. Does anyone have experience with this interface or can give me some good example of using it for syntax coloring and intellisense.

Maybe you know other way to achive my goal, but please don't send me links to third-party solutions.

Answer (score 0):

May be it helps you [DSL Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126235.aspx)
or this [antlr](http://antlr.org/)